# How to maximize a window to more displays on Gnome 3?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell

How to maximize a window in Gnome 3 to f.e. two 1080p screens in pivot?

I've seen some relevant answers but not for Gnome 3 which is now "most default" windows environment in the Linux world.